# Spotfire - Data source reference missing while moving library & data source from 5.5 to 6.5 server

Tags: datasource, tibco, spotfire

Steps Followed:

1. From 5.5 server, Exported Data Source & Library(Elements/InfoLinks/Reports) as two separate exports
2. Copied these files to the 6.5 folder (tomcat/application-data/...)
3. From 6.5 server,

   a. Imported the data source first (need to edit and input the password and save it. otherwise giving me error)

   b. Now import the library items(3 parts).

At this point, getting the error for missing references (mainly data source itself is not referenced). Logs attached.
Tried multiple times of deleting/importing with different combinations of replace/add  new items etc.

Setup Details:

1. Spotfire database on 5.5 is Oracle (Express Edition) whereas on 6.5 its MS SQL Server(Trial Version)
2. Data Source being imported & exported is MySQL.
3. Both 5.5 & 6.5 is on the same physical server and running only one at any given time.

My Questions:

1. Is there any specific sequence in order to export(5.5) & import(6.5) library & data sources?
2. Does both DataSource & Library has to be exported & imported in one single shot or am i missing something?
3. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, but I was doing the export/import process from 5.0 to 6.5.
However, the following steps solved the issue:

1. Export and import only the data source(s) first (it can be done easily if you keep the data source(s) in a separete folder)
2. Export and import all the elements/columns (again it can be done easily only if you have these in a separate folder)
3. Export and import the infolinks
4. Export and import the reports